# What is the vapour coming out from the mouth called?

Tags: single-word-requests

In cold weather, we get water vapour coming out of the mouth as we breathe. What is that called?

Comment: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1110663

Comment: If that link is why I got the negative vote, can you please see the two answers below? There doesn't seem to be an agreed upon answer -- hence my question.

Comment: The downvote is because the question shows no research effort. The link contains the same information as both the answers.

Comment: @Hugo: while that thread could possibly used as the basis of an answer, it is not even remotely an authoritative source, and the website it's on is not a general reference. (You can find lots of answers on the internet, but that doesn't mean they're *correct* answers.)

Comment: Not quite the same issue, but here is my very first question on ELU (sigh, nostalgia), about water vapour rising from a body of water; there were many different opinions. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63677/what-is-the-connotation-of-the-noun-steam

Comment: Some people call it *fog breath*, *foggy breath*, *frost breath*, *frosty breath*, or *cold breath*. You can Google any of those terms. There is a whole outdoor industry (hunters, snow mobilers, etc.) for counteracting it. (There are also some games and computer scripts that have co-opted some of the terms.)

Comment: I made up a word for it as a child. "Hurh" just the sound you can make exhaling hard. As in "I put some hurh on my computer screen and wiped it clean".

Comment: There are a dozen different terms that might be used (with varying degrees of technical accuracy) -- steam, fog, vapor, smoke, mist, haze, etc -- but "seeing your breath" is (based on my 66 years of experience observing it, in the US) the most common idiom, with "steam" probably second in popularity.  And children are more apt to say "smoke".  (And I've never really observed any regionalisms related to this, though in the southern US the phenomenon is obviously less frequent.)

Comment: Relevant: [Is "steamy breath" more commonly used in hot or cold settings?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/276182/is-steamy-breath-more-commonly-used-in-cold-or-hot-settings/276184#276184)

Comment: I think the answer lies in the question itself... You're not going to get much better than vapor or steamy breath.

Comment: I say "foggy breath".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is simply called "breath", with no special word for the visible form. We often call this phenomenon "seeing one's breath":

> It's so cold **I can see my breath**!

Comment: That's disappointing :(

Comment: @recluze Why? There is no special single word for most things.

Comment: This "single-word-request" idea is a mistake, I think. It's like asking for the single Chinese character for any concept. Mostly there isn't one. There are compounds, which are much more common, and there are constructions, which are vastly more important than single words (or characters).

Comment: @recluze: It's just the way you say things in English. 'Your breath is fogging up the window' works whether you can see the vapor in the air or not.

Comment: @recluze Old post, but to respond to this, I think it's because the English language evolved in a cold climate...And because seeing your breath in such areas was so common and passive, there was no really a specific word for it. Just my weird theory...

Answer (score 1):

I would call that ***steam*** (definition 2b from [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steam):  *the mist formed by the condensation on cooling of water vapor*); even though it is most commonly associated with boiling, the word can be applied to any vapor created due to a heat differential.

(one example from the definition page:  *Their breath **steamed** the windows.*)

Comment: The condensation and fog formed a window or glass might be called "steam", but I don't believe the word properly applies to one's visible breath.

Comment: why does the condensation have to land on glass in order to be called steam?

Comment: @Mark: As a matter of fact, people do sometimes refer to this vapor as "steam". From [this website](http://www.ehow.com/how_6171602_make-vapor-come-out-mouth.html): _When condensation occurs, the invisible water vapor changes from a gas to tiny particles of liquid water suspended in the air. This results in clouds **or the visible steam** that can come out of your mouth._ The word _steam_ isn't restricted to the vapor that comes from **boiling**; think of the expression _steamy shower_, for example.

Comment: I downvoted it. I agree that people *could* and often *do* describe it with many circumlocutions like "visible steam that can come out of the mouth" or "clouds". I disagree that these are readily accepted and unambiguous terms, and calling the phenomenon "clouds" or "steam" on a regular basis will be regarded as either metaphorical or disfluent.

Comment: +1 I'd call it steam or mist, though I don't disagree with calling it "breath" as per @MarkBeadles answer, so +1 for him too.

Comment: To put it another way: none of "mist", "steam", or "clouds" refer *specifically* to the visible condensation of one's breath in the cold, which is what the questioner was asking.

Comment: @Mark: **steam** def. 2b (M-W): "the mist formed by the condensation on cooling of water vapor" ...that wouldn't count?

Comment: @J.R. I don't want to give the questioner the impression that the correct single word for the phenomenon is "steam" in the way that the single word for Canis familiaris is "dog". It *could* be steam, but it could be mist, it could be fog, it could be breath, it could be vapor, it could be "condensation droplets", depending on speaker choice. We don't call visible breath a special name.

Comment: @markBeadles, I have to disagree; in my area of the US, referring to the phenomenon in question as *steam* will be immediately understood.  It is perhaps more common to refer to it in verb form ("our breath *steamed* as we rode the J-bar to the top of the slope"), but the noun is certainly standard as well.  (Also, English is not a language that  generally admits to only one "correct single word" for any given thing, as my hound would tell you if it could.  He is a friendly pooch, after all.)

Comment: "English is not a language that generally admits to only one "correct single word" for any given thing" <-- my point exactly!

Comment: In my experience, however, the most common single word used for the phenomenon is indeed *steam*.  The dictionary supports this usage.

Answer (score 0):

Fog.
an opaque mass of something in the atmosphere.

Answer (score 0):

> **comet-tail**  n. the tail of, or a tail like that of, a comet.
>
> a1769   W. Falconer Descr. Ninety-gun Ship (R.),   Its huge mast..From
>   which a bloody pendant stretch'd afar Its comet-tail, denouncing ample
>   war.

[OED]  http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/36875?redirectedFrom=comet%20tail#eid8982889

Answer (score 0):

Why not call it

> the breath condensing into mist

?

Example:

> It was so cold that I could see my **breath condensing into mist**.