# Is "steamy breath" more commonly used in cold or hot settings?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Example:

> We waited, holding our steamy breaths.

I think this could be interpreted in two ways: their breaths are steamy because it's cold (the heat is coming from inside). Or it's steamy because the air is hot and humid (the heat is coming from outside). Not sure which situation is more common, though. So I'd like to hear some opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really interesting question, and upon Googling, I found out that there has been much debate on whether the breath one exhales in a temperate climate is referred to as a 'steamy breath' or simply just, 'breath'.

Of course, the reason for this occurrence is because of a scientific process is called condensation. When you exhale when it's cold outside, the water vapor in your breath condenses into lots of tiny droplets of liquid water and ice (solid water) that you can see in the air as a cloud, similar to fog.

However, it is argued that steam is only produced when water is heated, and when we exhale, the process occurring is condensation, so is it technically correct to use the phrase 'steamy breath'?

The description of the white, cloudy gas when exhaled is simply referred to as - vapour:

> a substance diffused or suspended in the air, especially one normally liquid or solid

I think that the word 'steamy' here is used because of the similar observation is made when boiling - white solid gas appears. However, it is scientifically wrong to refer to it as a 'steamy' breath, as steam is,

> the vapour into which water is converted when *heated*, forming a white mist of minute water droplets in the air

Although the act of both steaming and exhaling in a cold climate both lead to similar observations, the process occurring in both scenarios are different. The 'steamy breath' can simply be referred to as 'breath', for example,

> "I can see my breath when I exhale."

In the case of your example, 'steamy breath' implies the fact that they have just took part in an intense activity, and are currently holding back their breath because of waiting for something to happen.
Similarly, another word used in the same context would be *bated breath*, meaning

> the condition of waiting for something to happen; subdued breathing due to high emotion

'Steamy breath' most likely originated from areas with cold climates, due to description of the white clouds and the same observation of that with boiling, that is why, 'steamy' breath.

Comment: I'm confused by that quotation; is steam the vapor or the white mist? it seems to say it is only the former, but water vapor is invisible IIRC (at least according to the scientific definition), and I think most people talking about steam actually mean to refer to both the (invisible) vapor and the (visible) mist. (

Comment: Steam is is the vapor which water is converted when heated, which is the product of boiling. In temperate countries, the exhalation is referred to as 'steamy' because of the similar characteristic (white suspension, white mist) to boiling. @sumelic

Comment: Okay. It just seems odd to me to argue that "steamy breath" is scientifically wrong, while at the same time describing it as "gas," "vapor" or "solid gas," which are all just as scientifically wrong.

Comment: It is scientifically wrong because steam is only produced through heating, whereas the white mist produced through exhalation is a process of condensation. @sumelic

Answer (score 0):

In a non-emotive setting, "steamy breath" would be used in a cold weather situation. It contrasts the warmth of the breath with the coldness of the surroundings.

It also refers to the fact that the condensation from the breath is visible. From a physics point of view, this is incorrect use as it is the condensation (water) and not the steam (water vapour) that is seen. But that's not really relevant to this question.

The other common use of "steamy" would be in a sexual sense. British tabloids often refer to the sexual activities of celebrities as "steamy". The expression is also used in the United states, as evidenced from the Tina Turner song *steamy windows* which is basically a pun on these two different meanings of steamy. In this sense "steamy breath" would refer to a "hot" situation, but not in the literal sense of hot weather.